# How can I get the name of the list that I set myself?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a raw list like this:

```
   var listRaw = [
    {
      "listName": "listA",
      "listValue": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      "listName": "listB",
      "listValue": [4, 5, 6]
    },
    {
      "listName": "listC",
      "listValue": [7, 8, 9]
    }
  ];
```

and empty lists like this:

```
  List<int> listA = [];
  List<int> listB = [];
  List<int> listD = [];

  List<List<int>> listFilled = [listA, listB, listD];
```

How can I get the names of empty lists as a condition to add `listVaule` in `listRaw` to them if name of empty list `== listName`? => **then `listFilled` will have the result `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], []]`**

So pls help me, this is my code so far

```
void main() {
  var listRaw = [
    {
      "listName": "listA",
      "listValue": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      "listName": "listB",
      "listValue": [4, 5, 6]
    },
    {
      "listName": "listC",
      "listValue": [7, 8, 9]
    }
  ];

  List<int> listA = [];
  List<int> listB = [];
  List<int> listD = [];

  List<List<int>> listFilled = [listA, listB, listD];

  listRaw.forEach((r) {
    listFilled.forEach((f) {
      if (r['listName'] ==  ___ ) { // How to get name of (f)
        f.addAll(r['listValue']);
      }
    });
  });

  print(listFilled); // want result: [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], []]
}
```

Comment: putting ```listA```,```listB``` and ```listD``` into ```listFilled``` will only add the elements of those three lists into ```filledList``` not its name.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names that you use are for you to understand what the variable is being used for. The compiler does not know what you named them. It only knows that this variable is pointing towards a specific point of memory.

That being said, what you can do is create your own subclass of the `List` class which will have a name attached to it. In that way, you can check the name of the List when you want to compare it. Your subclass should be something like this

*This is not exact syntax. Just an overview of what needs to be done.*

```
class MyNamedList extends List {
    String name;

    MyNamedList(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

//You can check for name like this
if (r['listName'] == myNamedListObj.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listRaw = [
    {
      "listName": "listA",
      "listValue": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      "listName": "listB",
      "listValue": [4, 5, 6]
    },
    {
      "listName": "listC",
      "listValue": [7, 8, 9]
    }
  ];
```

this is a List of Map<String, dynamic>

so what you need to do is create empty List<Map<String,dynamic>>

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> list = List.empty(growable:true);//set false if size is fixed.
```

Then `List<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> listFilled = [list1,list2,list3];`